# Focus on fields "in which" vs "that" you can become good at

Tags: word-choice

Focus on fields **in which** you can become good at.

vs

Focus on fields **that** you can become good at.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use 'which' or 'in which' or 'that' (as relative pronouns)?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/when-to-use-which-or-in-which-or-that-as-relative-pronouns) If the answer there seems a bit too technical, have a look at [that / in which / in that / which](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27366/that-in-which-in-that-which)

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is grammatical and idiomatic as it is written. The first is not, because it has a double preposition. The first sentence becomes grammatical if you drop the final "at".

> Focus on fields in which you can become good.

Comment: Well spotted! I missed the extraneous ***at*** in OP's first example. I doubt that was intended though - probably just what happens when you're doing cut&paste in a foreign language. StoneyB's excellent answer in the linked "duplicate" goes into the syntactic implications of preposition placement in these contexts though.